# `kube-proxy` uses `iptables` mode, what is the access principle?

Tags: kubernetes

`kube- proxy` uses `iptables` mode, what is the access principle?

---

Is it `client --> iptables --> pod` or `client --> iptables --> kube-proxy --> pod` ?

I've read elsewhere that it's  `client --> iptables --> pod`, but I've actually looked at it in the cluster and found that this is not the case.

```bash
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -S -t nat | grep  -e "-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU"
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns -> 10.244.239.184:53" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-QZKT3GTHGHPWIPHL
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns -> 10.244.239.185:53" -j KUBE-SEP-JN7UQ4Z24ZZERE5A
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -S -t nat | grep  -e "-A KUBE-SEP-JN7UQ4Z24ZZERE5A"
-A KUBE-SEP-JN7UQ4Z24ZZERE5A -s 10.244.239.185/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-JN7UQ4Z24ZZERE5A -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -S -t nat | grep  -e "-A KUBE-SEP-QZKT3GTHGHPWIPHL"
-A KUBE-SEP-QZKT3GTHGHPWIPHL -s 10.244.239.184/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-QZKT3GTHGHPWIPHL -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
┌──[root@vms100.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$
```

It seems to be back to `kube-proxy`, and the `endpoint` mapped chains are sent to arbitrary ports, which doesn't match my perception. Something like
Using the `userspack` pattern

Also the `-mode random --probability 0.50000000000` load method of `iptables` doesn't make sense, they should all `DNAT` to any port

---

I want to know what is the problem there, my cluster version is `v1.25.1`, the `-mode` field in `kube-proxy` is null, how should I interpret it? Please let me know if you have any ideas, I'd appreciate it!

I read in the official documentation that iptables uses `userspack` if the version is too old, my `iptables` version is `v1.4.21`, is that the reason?

https://v1-25.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-proxy-config.v1alpha1/#kubeproxy-config-k8s-io-v1alpha1-ProxyMode

I have seen many people say that it will be like this

```bash
-A KUBE-SEP-2KC5TQ77EILRJT77 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/test-goweb:80-8090" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.244.240.51:8090
```

Now this is the case

```bash
-A KUBE-SEP-QZKT3GTHGHPWIPHL -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination :0 --persistent --to-destination
```

Comment: Kube-proxy is a service which provides abstraction for the remaining services deployed in kubernetes. Hence, in this scenario it is different from normal IPtable rules since kube-proxy is creating the rules it will be like 

`Client —> kube-proxy —> IPtables —> pod`

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni  Thank you very much, I think I understand what you mean, you are saying that `iptables` rules, including custom chains, are dynamically generated and adjusted by `kube-proxy`, my problem is that the last chain generated should be `DNAT` to a specific `Pod`, but I see that all my clusters are `DNAT` to any port

Comment: Hi @山河以无恙 can you give the deployment code or commands for replicating the issue, so that it will help us in providing better answer..